# issue with read user from database

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, tapestry

hi i have problem with logging, first i registered user in database,this works ok! then when i try to logged with that user(username and password),application trhows me exception:

```
       ` [ERROR] ioc.Registry id to load is required for loading
[ERROR] ioc.Registry Operations trace:
[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 1] Triggering event 'action' on Login:loginform
[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 2] Triggering event 'validate' on Login:username
[ERROR] TapestryModule.RequestExceptionHandler Processing of request failed with uncaught exception: id to load is required for loading
org.apache.tapestry5.runtime.ComponentEventException: id to load is required for loading [at classpath:com/fit/pages/Login.tml, line 7]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1152)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.access$3000(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$7.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1077)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$7.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1074)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:68)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1063)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.invoke(ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.java:141)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1073)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventRequestHandlerImpl.handle(ComponentEventRequestHandlerImpl.java:81)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ImmediateActionRenderResponseFilter.handle(ImmediateActionRenderResponseFilter.java:42)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_13194654f69.handle($ComponentEventRequestHandler_13194654f69.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AjaxFilter.handle(AjaxFilter.java:42)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_13194654f69.handle($ComponentEventRequestHandler_13194654f69.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$39.handle(TapestryModule.java:2583)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_13194654f69.handle($ComponentEventRequestHandler_13194654f69.java)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_13194654e1b.handle($ComponentEventRequestHandler_13194654e1b.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.handleComponentEvent(ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.java:43)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.InitializeActivePageName.handleComponentEvent(InitializeActivePageName.java:39)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_13194654e1d.handleComponentEvent($ComponentRequestHandler_13194654e1d.java)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_13194654e01.handleComponentEvent($ComponentRequestHandler_13194654e01.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventDispatcher.dispatch(ComponentEventDispatcher.java:46)
    at $Dispatcher_13194654e03.dispatch($Dispatcher_13194654e03.java)
    at $Dispatcher_13194654dfe.dispatch($Dispatcher_13194654dfe.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$RequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:321)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:26)
    at $RequestHandler_13194654dff.service($RequestHandler_13194654dff.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$4.service(TapestryModule.java:984)
    at $RequestHandler_13194654dff.service($RequestHandler_13194654dff.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:974)
    at $RequestHandler_13194654dff.service($RequestHandler_13194654dff.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
    at $RequestHandler_13194654dff.service($RequestHandler_13194654dff.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:85)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:103)
    at $RequestHandler_13194654dff.service($RequestHandler_13194654dff.java)
    at $RequestHandler_13194654df5.service($RequestHandler_13194654df5.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:272)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_13194654df7.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_13194654df7.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_13194654df4.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_13194654df4.java)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_13194654df7.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_13194654df7.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:928)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_13194654df7.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_13194654df7.java)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_13194654df2.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_13194654df2.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1148)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:387)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:880)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:747)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: id to load is required for loading [at classpath:com/fit/pages/Login.tml, line 15]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form.executeStoredActions(Form.java:681)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form._$advised$onAction(Form.java:542)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form$onAction$invocation_13194657e97.invokeAdvisedMethod(Form$onAction$invocation_13194657e97.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.java:77)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.LoggingAdvice.advise(LoggingAdvice.java:37)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.LogWorker$1.advise(LogWorker.java:54)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.java:86)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form.onAction(Form.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form$MethodAccess_onAction_13194654e6d.invoke(Form$MethodAccess_onAction_13194654e6d.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.BaseEventHandlerMethodInvoker.invokeEventHandlerMethod(BaseEventHandlerMethodInvoker.java:52)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.OnEventWorker$4.invokeEventHandlers(OnEventWorker.java:157)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.OnEventWorker$4.advise(OnEventWorker.java:136)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.java:86)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form.dispatchComponentEvent(Form.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:950)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1132)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: id to load is required for loading [at classpath:com/fit/pages/Login.tml, line 15]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:69)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:68)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1063)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.invoke(ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.java:141)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1073)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1046)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.InternalComponentResourcesImpl.triggerEvent(InternalComponentResourcesImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.FieldValidationSupportImpl.validate(FieldValidationSupportImpl.java:164)
    at $FieldValidationSupport_13194654e8f.validate($FieldValidationSupport_13194654e8f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.base.AbstractTextField.processSubmission(AbstractTextField.java:211)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.base.AbstractField.processSubmission(AbstractField.java:190)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.base.AbstractField.access$100(AbstractField.java:38)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.base.AbstractField$ProcessSubmission.execute(AbstractField.java:95)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.base.AbstractField$ProcessSubmission.execute(AbstractField.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form.executeStoredActions(Form.java:666)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.runtime.ComponentEventException: id to load is required for loading [at classpath:com/fit/pages/Login.tml, line 15]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1152)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.access$3000(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$7.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1077)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$7.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1074)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:65)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
    at org.hibernate.event.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.event.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:840)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:836)
    at $Session_13194654f6e.get($Session_13194654f6e.java)
    at $Session_13194654dd6.get($Session_13194654dd6.java)
    at com.fit.hibernate.UsersServiceHibernate.retriveSingleUser(UsersServiceHibernate.java:41)
    at $Users_13194654f6a.retriveSingleUser($Users_13194654f6a.java)
    at $Users_13194654f6d.retriveSingleUser($Users_13194654f6d.java)
    at $Users_13194654e62.retriveSingleUser($Users_13194654e62.java)
    at com.fit.util.Security.authenticate(Security.java:11)
    at com.fit.pages.Login.onValidate(Login.java:50)
    at com.fit.pages.Login$MethodAccess_onValidate_13194654e64.invoke(Login$MethodAccess_onValidate_13194654e64.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.BaseEventHandlerMethodInvoker.invokeEventHandlerMethod(BaseEventHandlerMethodInvoker.java:52)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.OnEventWorker$4.invokeEventHandlers(OnEventWorker.java:157)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.OnEventWorker$4.advise(OnEventWorker.java:136)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.java:86)
    at com.fit.pages.Login.dispatchComponentEvent(Login.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:942)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1132)
    ... 98 more
```

here is my code:

```
@Entity
public class UserBean implements User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Basic
    private String userName;
    @Basic
    private String fullName;
    @Basic
    private String password;
    @Basic
    private String email;
    @Basic
    private Gender gender;
    @Basic
    private AccountRole role;




    public UserBean() {

    }
    public UserBean( String userName,  String password
            ) {


        this.userName = userName;

        this.password = password;

    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#getId()
     */
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#setId(long)
     */
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#getUserName()
     */
     @Validate("required")
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#setUserName(java.lang.String)
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#getFullName()
     */
     @Validate("required")
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#setFullName(java.lang.String)
     */
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#getPassword()
     */
     @Validate("required")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#setPassword(java.lang.String)
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#getEmail()
     */
     @Validate("required")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#setEmail(java.lang.String)
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#getGender()
     */
    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#setGender(com.fit.enums.Gender)
     */
    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#getRole()
     */
    public AccountRole getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.beans.User#setRole(com.fit.enums.AccountRole)
     */
    public void setRole(AccountRole role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


}
```

login page:

```
public class Login {

    private String userName;

    @Property
    private String password;

    @Inject
    @Property
    private Users users;

    @SessionState
    private User user;

    @Component(id="loginForm")
    private Form loginForm;

    @Inject
    private Messages messages;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }



    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;

    }
    void onValidate(){
        User authenticatedUser = Security.authenticate(userName, password , users);
        if(authenticatedUser != null){
            user = authenticatedUser;
        }else{
            loginForm.recordError(messages.get("authentication-failed"));
        }
    }

    Object onSuccess()
    {
        return Index.class;
    }
```

security.java

```
public class Security {

    public static User authenticate(String userName,String password, Users users ){
        User login = null;

        login = users.retriveSingleUser(userName);
        if(login == null) return null;

        if(login.getPassword().equals(password)){
            return login;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

usersBean.java

```
public class UsersBean implements Users {

    private Map<String, User> users;

    public UsersBean(Map<String, User> users) {

        this.users = users;
    }

    public UsersBean() {
        users = new HashMap<String, User>();
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.service.Users#save(com.fit.interfaces.User)
     */
    @CommitAfter
    public User save(User user){
        return users.put(user.getUserName(), user);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.service.Users#retrive()
     */
    public Collection<User> retrive(){
        return users.values();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.service.Users#retriveSingleUser(java.lang.String)
     */

    public User retriveSingleUser(String userName){
        return users.get(userName);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.fit.service.Users#retriveSingleUser(java.io.Serializable)
     */
//  public User retriveSingleUser(Serializable id){
//      return users.get(id);
//  }

}
```

usersServiceHibernate.java

```
public class UsersServiceHibernate implements Users {

    private Session session;



    public UsersServiceHibernate(Session session) {

        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (User) session.get(UserBean.class, session.save(user));
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<User> retrive() {
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserBean.class);
        return criteria.list();
    }

    @Override
    public User retriveSingleUser(String userName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (User) session.get(UserBean.class, userName);
    }


//  public User retriveSingleUser(Serializable id) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      return (User) session.get(UserBean.class, id);
//  }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:name</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_value">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="com.fit.beans.UserBean"/>

        <mapping package="com.fit.beans"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

how to make method for hibernate read data from database???

Comment: Every row in a database, needs an id. I don't see there the @Id annotation or similar(Does class User or UserBean have an attribute long id?). Also the error says that the error is located at `Login.tml line 7` you did not post at all the code that is making you trouble. I suggest you edit the question a bit more if you want to get an accurate answer.

Comment: User is interface UserBean is class and UserBean have attribute "id"

Comment: Mixing Tapestry with Hibernate doesn't help if you aren't using Hibernate correctly, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm missing the code for your User and there will very likely be a bunch of "caused by" stacktraces in your exception which will point you to the problem (check your logs and not just the tapestry error page). You seem to be mixing your Service layer, DAO layer and model layer all into one here. Also you are caching your users in a Map and I can't seem to find the trace to you actual hibernate session calls. I'm trying to trace those as pretty certain your problem lies there.

The `session.get(UserBean.class, userName);` takes the primary key of the UserBean, but in your case UserBean seems to be a Service without any mapping associated with it. Also, generally primary keys are `Long`'s. To retrieve a UserBean by its username have a look at the [hiberante criteria documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).

The exception you are seeing might happen when you call get with a null primary key. But you'll need to post the full stacktrace for me to be sure.

I would advice you to have a good look at the [tapestry hibernate](http://tapestry.apache.org/hibernate.html) examples as you are setting yourself up for quite an unreadable project like this.

Good luck,
Joost

Comment: hi thanks for helping me :), i add code for UserBean and full stacktrace of exception

Comment: The answer is already there. "The session.get(UserBean.class, userName); takes the primary key". You are passing in the username String. Hibernate cannot guess that you would like you to match that to the username column. Have a look at the hibernate criteria API. (I updated the answer and added a link to this)